# Is there a way to specify the default Copy&Paste behavior of formatted text to be "text-only"?

Tags: windows

I rarely, if ever, care about the source formatting when I copy&paste some text.  Often I keep Notepad open simply to paste into it and copy the text back into the clipboard.

Is there a way to set the default behavior to omit the formatting?

Comment: I think word and excel have options for that on the right click and edit menu, pasta as plain text.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to replace the default clipboard with something else, but if so, this might also influence the ability to copy/paste images.

Answer (score 1):

A "default" text-only copy-paste action implies the ability to also do
the alternate rich-text copy-paste.
Some applications support both actions, but not all
applications have this feature.

If you wish to differentiate the two actions globally in Windows,
you need third-party software.

One such software is the free
[PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/):

> PureText is a tiny tray utility that removes all text formatting from your clipboard and optionally pastes the resulting pure text to the active window with a single hotkey.
>
> The easiest way to use PureText is to simply use its Hotkey to paste text instead of using the standard CTRL+V Hotkey that is built into most Windows applications. To configure PureText, right-click on its tray icon and choose "Options" from the pop-up menu. The default Hotkey is WINDOWS+V, but this can be changed. In this Options window, you can also configure PureText to run each time you start Windows.

You may also do it yourself, using
[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
as your tool. An example AutoHotKey script can be found in the post
[Paste plain text (and copy/cut)](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/10412-paste-plain-text-and-copycut/).

If you wish to go the AutoHotKey way, you may even set
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to do text-only copy-paste,
and some other hotkey to do rich-text copy-paste.